# Visual Studio 2017 Workspaces: How to set the default workspace?

Tags: visual-studio-2017, azure-devops, workspace, team-explorer

The latest update (2nd week of March, 2018) to VS seems to have broken it's ability to remember my workspace.

Prior to the update, I had no problems:  I would open VS, click the Team Explorer tab, and it would automatically connect to the last team project I was in and show the list of solutions.  In effect, it remembered my workspace (SELMER-LAPTOP).

After the update:  I open VS and go to the Team Explorer tab and I see several prompts to "Configure your workspace" to open solutions for this project:

[image]

If I go into "Configure your workspace" and click Advanced, I get the Add Workspace dialog prompting me to add "SELMER-LAPTOP-1" workspace:

[image]

Oddly enough, I cancel out of all of that and then select the "Work Items" tab in Team Explorer, then go back to Team Explorer home, and it reconnects to my original Workspace:

[image]

For some reason, VS seems to have forgotten how to connect to my workspace when I launch VS.  It still knows about it (as evidenced by the fact that I merely have to click the "Work Items" tab and then go back to Home for it to remember).

What's going on here?  Is there some way to get VS to connect to my original workspace as it did before the update?

Thanks,
Steve

Answer (score 2):

I can also reproduce the issue. And it mainly appears when the first time to open the updated VS.

I have reported the issue [VS shows "You must configure your workspace mappings to open solutions for this project" for TFVC repo after VS updated](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/221565/vs-shows-you-must-configure-your-workspace-mapping.html), and you can follow up.